# Gradle, CI/CD, monorepo: How to deploy/publish only changed subprojects when merged to main?

Tags: gradle, monorepo, cicd

So we're suffering a lot with a microservice architecture.

Each microservice has its own repo and CI/CD (github action deploy service on merge to main)

But there are a lot of caveats, among them: They share a lot of code, so we're using internal artifactory to publish shared libraries. And that comes with a lot of trouble too.

For shared artifacts we used a monorepo and that made everything way easier, and that got us thinking: Well, let's make a monorepo for all the microservices (they're not that many anyway).

But then, how do we do CI/CD

- A branch per microservice (like a "main" for every microservice)?
- A smart script that identifies which subprojects were modified?
- Some info in the commit comment that tells Github action which subproject to deploy?

Those all seem like ugly workarounds. Has anyone experienced this, and solved it elegantly?

Comment: I thought of triggering the build of all modules every time, while using Gradles Cache and incremental builds within CI, and compare hashes of the generated jar artifacts to determine what has changed and needs redeployment and what not. Otherwise, when using git to determine changes, you might have a hard time with transitive dependency modules. If a shared lib has changed, how to detect which applications have to be rebuilt and deployed? Drawback is you have to remember somewhere what the last deployed hashes were or access the last artifacts on the fly. Have you gotten any solution yet?

Comment: This might be interesting for your case as well https://github.com/melix/includegit-gradle-plugin

Comment: This might also be interesting https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jnxplus/nx-boot-gradle